# How do I hide a button from cell rendered component in Ag-Grid?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-react

I have a list of button in mcomponent that I am using to show it in the grid for performing actions on the grid. I need to hide on of them.

My code is somewhat like this:

```
let cols = [{
    field: '',
    headerName: 'Actions',
    width: 250,
    colId: 'params',
    cellRendererFramework: 'gridEditButtons'
  }];
```

This is the first column of my grid and then I am concatenating the rest in this logic. So, I am able to hide columns but what if the cellRendererFramework: 'gridEditButtons' has 5 buttons and I want to hide 2 columns that are in the black box in below image.

[image]

**HTML Code for GridEditbuttons.Vue**

```
<template>
<div>
<!-- Approve Button -->
<!-- <v-tooltip bottom>
<v-btn fab small style="height: 23px; width:23px; margin-top: 0px;"
    color="primary" slot="activator"
    @click.stop="approveRow">
    <v-icon>fa-check</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<span>Approve</span>
</v-tooltip> -->
<!-- Release Button -->
<!-- <v-tooltip bottom>
<v-btn fab small style="height: 23px; width:23px; margin-top: 0px;"
    color="primary" slot="activator"
    @click.stop="releaseRow">
    <v-icon>fa-paper-plane</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<span>Release</span>
</v-tooltip> -->
<!-- Edit Button -->
<v-tooltip bottom>
<v-btn fab small style="height: 23px; width:23px; margin-top: 0px;"
    color="primary" slot="activator"
    @click.stop="editRow">
    <v-icon>fa-pencil-alt</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<span>Edit</span>
</v-tooltip>
<!-- Delete Button -->
<v-tooltip bottom>
<v-btn xs4 fab small style="height: 23px; width:23px; margin-top: 0px;"
    color="primary" slot="activator"
    @click.stop="deleteRow">
    <v-icon>fa-trash-alt</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<span>Delete</span>
</v-tooltip>
<!-- View Button -->
<!-- calls to function viewRow in this file when clicked on-->
<v-tooltip bottom>
<v-btn xs4 fab small style="height: 23px; width:23px; margin-top: 0px;"
    color="primary" slot="activator"
    @click.stop="viewRow">
    <v-icon>fa-book</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<span>View</span>
</v-tooltip>
</div>
</template>
```

**Script in GridEditButtons.Vue**

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
data () {
return {
  dialogDelete: false,
  execStatusDialog: false
};
},
methods: {
deleteRow () {
  // pass the id and collection name to delete here
  let rowObj = this.params.api.getRowNode(this.params.rowIndex);
  if (!rowObj || !rowObj.data) {
    return this.params.context.vm.alert('error', '', 'Unable to identify the selected record.');
  }
  this.params.context.vm.tableDeleteBtnClicked(rowObj);
  this.dialogDelete = !this.dialogDelete;
  },
  // Executes when the edit button in the grid is clicked
  editRow (event) {
  let rowObj = this.params.api.getRowNode(this.params.rowIndex);
  // Checks to see if a row is selected or if the selected row has data
  if (!rowObj || !rowObj.data) {
    // If it doesn't then an error is thrown
    return this.params.context.vm.alert('error', '', 'Unable to identify the selected record.');
    }
  // calls the tableEditBtnClicked method in the Brightspot file
  this.params.context.vm.tableEditBtnClicked(rowObj);
},
// Executes when the view button in the grid is clicked
viewRow (event) {
  // Gets the selected row
  let rowObj = this.params.api.getRowNode(this.params.rowIndex);
  // Checks to see if a row is selected or if the selected row has data
  if (!rowObj || !rowObj.data) {
    // If it doesn't then throw an error
    return this.params.context.vm.alert(
      'error',
      '',
      'Unable to identify the selected record.'
    );
  }
  // Calls the tableViewBtnClicked method in Brightspot file
  this.params.context.vm.tableViewBtnClicked(rowObj);
},
approveRow (event) {
  alert('Approved!'); // chunk of code
},
releaseRow (event) {
  alert('Released!'); // chunk of code
}
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the gridEditButtons code?

Comment: @AlienTechnology added

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Vue's [v-show or v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)?  This example shows hiding the Approve icon.

HTML

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <v-btn v-show="showApproveIcon" fab small style="height: 23px; width:23px; margin-top: 0px;"
    color="primary" slot="activator"
    @click.stop="approveRow">
    <v-icon>fa-check</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <span>Approve</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Script

```
data () {
  return {
    dialogDelete: false,
    execStatusDialog: false,
    showApproveIcon: false,
  };
},
```